# Is Martial Arts SE dead?

Tags: discussion

Seeing the site's states on Area51, should we throw in the towel?

If not, what should we do to make this site more popular?

Clearly, I am all for improving things... Just to be clear.

Answer (score 4):

No. It is not dead.  SE (the parent organization) is the one that decides when a SE is dead,  and until then it is best to act otherwise–people have been declaring the site doomed and/or dead since before we were out of private beta.   Meanwhile, some of our metrics (e.g., new page views) have even been improving.

It needs, and has always needed, people to act as advocates and to draw people to ask great questions, and then themselves to ask great questions.  I am open to suggestions on how best to accomplish that.

Comment: +1. A way to generate more questions would be to "advertise" on other boards.  Maybe doing a weekly challenge with a "price".  Of course, SE would have to agree to send some swag.

Comment: The other big thing that you can do is ask questions ^_^ Try to make a goal for how many good questions you can post in a week, and aim for it.

Comment: Cut out the anal-retentive edits.  I'm leaving the site for that reason.  I've never seen anything like it even on the English SE.  I will not accept anyone changing my words.

Comment: A comment is not really the appropriate venue for such discussion, but general Stack Exchange policy is that we believe in the power of community editing.

Comment: And in general I support such for the purposes of clarity or formatting where necessary.

Comment: Also we currently have "excellent" 'answered' and 'answer ratio' rating in Area 51. That's probably giving us a life line.